# How to create such C++ function that would take enum as parameter/argument and also return it?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, enums, return

I have some enum defined like (in header):

```
typedef enum { METHOD, URL, URL_PARAM, URL_VALUE, VERSION, HEADER_KEY, HEADER_VALUE, BODY, OK } http_request_parser_state;
```

I try to create such function (in Cpp file):

```
    http_request_parser_state class_name::parse_buffer( http_request_parser_state parser_state)
{
 return parser_state;
}
```

But I get errors like:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'parse_buffer'   
Error   5   error C2371: 'parse_buffer' : redefinition; different basic 
etc
```

So how to define enum so it would be returnable and function argument at the same time?

Comment: There is nothing special to it. That simple code should work. Also the `typedef` is unneded if this is C++.

Comment: Are these two code fragments in the same source file or in separate header and source files and is there anything else between them?

Comment: Compiles fine with gcc and clang, both as C and as C++.

Comment: ended up passing `parser_state` as link and returning `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't your typedef, by chance, declared inside a class? If so - you should write `class_name::http_request_parser_state class_name::parse_buffer( http_request_parser_state parser_state)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are wrong in your code:
1. typedef declaration is unnecessary because all modern c++ compilers recognize enumerations as special types
2. declaration of enum goes this way: enum TypeName { Values } VariableNames;

So in order to work correctly, your code should look like this:

```
enum http_request_parser_state { METHOD, URL, URL_PARAM, URL_VALUE, VERSION, HEADER_KEY, HEADER_VALUE, BODY, OK };

http_request_parser_state class_name::parse_buffer( http_request_parser_state parser_state)
{
 return parser_state;
}
```

And that should work.

Comment: It is not neccessary to specify the enum name in C++.